# maven-deploy-plugin deploy-file goal insists on deploying javadoc file for previous deploy-file execution

Tags: maven, javadoc

I have a pom which I use to package some third party jars to deploy to a local nexus.
However it always fails with the second upload. It seems as if it is always picking up the javadoc associated with the first deploy-file execution, eventhough I have not specified this.

Is this a bug, or what am I doing wrong?

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>a.b.c</groupId>
  <artifactId>vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <properties>
    <vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadoczip>${basedir}/files/11.2.0.1.0/jdbc/javadoc.zip</vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadoczip>
    <vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadoctemp>${basedir}/files/11.2.0.1.0/jdbc/javadoctemp</vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadoctemp>
    <vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadocfile>${basedir}/files/11.2.0.1.0/jdbc/javadoctemp/thejavadocs.jar</vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadocfile>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare</id>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <echo message="repackge the vendorx javadoc zip to be in the expected format" />
                            <delete includeemptydirs="true">
                                <fileset dir="${vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadoctemp}" includes="**/*" defaultexcludes="false"/>
                             </delete>
                            <unzip src="${vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadoczip}" dest="${vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadoctemp}" />
                            <!--  N.B. vendorx zip version specific location - you will have to change this to make it work -->
                            <jar destfile="${vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadocfile}" basedir="${vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadoctemp}/E13995_02/html"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-library-main</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${basedir}/files/11.2.0.1.0/jdbc/lib/vjdbc99.jar</file>
                        <groupId>a.b.c.com.vendorx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vjdbc99</artifactId>
                        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-javadocs-main</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadocfile}</file>
                        <groupId>a.b.c.com.vendorx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vjdbc99</artifactId>
                        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>install-library-debug</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${basedir}/files/11.2.0.1.0/jdbc/lib/vjdbc99_g.jar</file>
                        <groupId>a.b.c.com.vendorx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vjdbc99_g</artifactId>
                        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>install-javadocs-debug</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--  same javadocs as for non debug -->
                        <file>${vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadocfile}</file>
                        <groupId>a.b.c.com.vendorx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vjdbc99_g</artifactId>
                        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <classifier>javadoc</classifier>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <!--  Don't bother deploying this POM ... its only the artifact we want to deploy -->
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>true</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <!--  This is the real thing we are deploying -->
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-library-main</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${basedir}/files/11.2.0.1.0/jdbc/lib/vjdbc99.jar</file>
                        <groupId>a.b.c.com.vendorx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vjdbc99</artifactId>
                        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        <javadoc>${vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper.javadocfile}</javadoc>

                        <url>http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
                        <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>

                    <id>deploy-library-debug</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <file>${basedir}/files/11.2.0.1.0/jdbc/lib/vjdbc99_g.jar</file>
                        <groupId>a.b.c.com.vendorx</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vjdbc99_g</artifactId>
                        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
                        <url>http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
                        <repositoryId>releases</repositoryId>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

      <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
          <id>releases</id>
          <url>http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <url>http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
      </distributionManagement>


</project>
```

Here's the output

```
C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper>mvn deploy
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-antrun-plugin:1.2:run (prepare) @ vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper ---
[INFO] Executing tasks
     [echo] repackge the vendorx javadoc zip to be in the expected format
    [unzip] Expanding: C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\files\11.2.0.1.0\jdbc\javadoc.zip into C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\files\11.2.0.1.0\j
dbc\javadoctemp
      [jar] Building jar: C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\files\11.2.0.1.0\jdbc\javadoctemp\thejavadocs.jar
[INFO] Executed tasks
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\pom.xml to C:\Users\wibble\.m2\repository\uk\co\his\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wr
apper-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (install-library-main) @ vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\files\11.2.0.1.0\jdbc\lib\vjdbc99.jar to C:\Users\wibble\.m2\repository\uk\co\his\com\vendorx\vjdbc99\11.2.0.1.0\ojdbc
6-11.2.0.1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\wibble\AppData\Local\Temp\1\mvninstall1181445077198226588.pom to C:\Users\wibble\.m2\repository\uk\co\his\com\vendorx\vjdbc99\11.2.0.1.0\vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (install-javadocs-main) @ vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\files\11.2.0.1.0\jdbc\javadoctemp\thejavadocs.jar to C:\Users\wibble\.m2\repository\uk\co\his\com\vendorx\vjdbc99\11.
2.0.1.0\vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0-javadoc.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (install-library-debug) @ vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\files\11.2.0.1.0\jdbc\lib\vjdbc99_g.jar to C:\Users\wibble\.m2\repository\uk\co\his\com\vendorx\vjdbc99_g\11.2.0.1.0\o
jdbc6_g-11.2.0.1.0.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\wibble\AppData\Local\Temp\1\mvninstall4548076073436253537.pom to C:\Users\wibble\.m2\repository\uk\co\his\com\vendorx\vjdbc99_g\11.2.0.1.0\vjdbc99_g-11.2.0.1.0.pom
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (install-javadocs-debug) @ vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\files\11.2.0.1.0\jdbc\javadoctemp\thejavadocs.jar to C:\Users\wibble\.m2\repository\uk\co\his\com\vendorx\vjdbc99_g\1
1.2.0.1.0\vjdbc99_g-11.2.0.1.0-javadoc.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact deployment
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (deploy-library-main) @ vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper ---
Uploading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0.jar
Uploaded: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0.jar (2062 KB at 3152.7 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0.pom
Uploaded: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0.pom (404 B at 8.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/maven-metadata.xml (316 B at 6.1 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0-javadoc.jar
Uploaded: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0-javadoc.jar (780 KB at 1621.4 KB/sec)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (deploy-library-debug) @ vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper ---
Uploading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99_g/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99_g-11.2.0.1.0.jar
Uploaded: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99_g/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99_g-11.2.0.1.0.jar (3323 KB at 2472.1 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99_g/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99_g-11.2.0.1.0.pom
Uploaded: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99_g/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99_g-11.2.0.1.0.pom (406 B at 6.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99_g/maven-metadata.xml
Uploading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99_g/maven-metadata.xml
Uploaded: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99_g/maven-metadata.xml (318 B at 4.7 KB/sec)
Uploading: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/11.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0-javadoc.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.311s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Jan 23 12:34:09 GMT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (deploy-library-debug) on project vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper: Error deploying attached artifact C:\Users\Adm
inistrator\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper\files\11.2.0.1.0\jdbc\javadoctemp\thejavadocs.jar: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact uk.co.his.com.vendorx:vjdbc99:jar:javadoc:11.2.
0.1.0 from/to releases (http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases): Failed to transfer file: http://foo.lan:8888/nexus/content/repositories/releases/a/b/c/com/vendorx/vjdbc99/1
1.2.0.1.0/vjdbc99-11.2.0.1.0-javadoc.jar. Return code is: 400 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
C:\Users\wibble\workspace\vendorx_jdbc_driver_wrapper>
```

I have created a bug on the deploy plugin jira:
[MDEPLOY-143](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MDEPLOY-143)

Answer (score 1):

Third party POMs will almost never play together nicely with your local Maven infrastructure.

The POM in question modifies the Maven build lifecycle by associating a number of goals with the phase `install`.

To deploy artifacts defined by that POM, I'd recommend you first create the artifacts by issuing a `mvn package` command. This will create the artifacts in your project's build folder (`target/`) but not send them to your local repository. Then upload them manually one by one into your repository.

If instead you prefer to deploy straight from that POM file, be prepared to do some serious editing beforehand.

As a side note: you might want to put such artifacts into a 3rd party repository inside your Nexus, not into `nexus/content/repositories/releases`, which is reserved for releases of your own software only (by convention).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So in essence using a POM as a quasi batch file is not a good thing, attempting to package something that is not the current artifact being constructed is not a good idea, use a 2 stage process - say Ant - to create the artifacts complete with pseudo POMs and then have ant drive maven (:-)) to do the deploy? But this stuff _ought_ to work?